# How to pass credentials to httpwebrequest for accessing SharePoint Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to read files from a SharePoint document library using `HttpWebRequest`.  In order to do that I have to pass some credentials.  I'm using the below request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/msexcel";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.01;+Windows+NT+5.0";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, PassWord);
```

Is this the correct way to pass credentials?

Answer (score 24):

You could also use:

```
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need to run request as the current user from desktop application use `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` (see [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx)).

Your code looks fine if you need to run a request from server side code or under a different user.

Please note that you should be careful when storing passwords - consider using the `SecureString` version of the constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much.Would you tell me what is meant by securestring conversion constructor.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to set the credentials on the fly, have a look at this source:

http://spc3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/57957#1015709

```
private ICredentials BuildCredentials(string siteurl, string username, string password, string authtype) {
    NetworkCredential cred;
    if (username.Contains(@"\")) {
        string domain = username.Substring(0, username.IndexOf(@"\"));
        username = username.Substring(username.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
    } else {
        cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
    }
    CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
    if (authtype.Contains(":")) {
        authtype = authtype.Substring(authtype.IndexOf(":") + 1); //remove the TMG: prefix
    }
    cache.Add(new Uri(siteurl), authtype, cred);
    return cache;
}
```