# Web API Getting 401 Unauthorized in IIS but works in IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api2, iis-express, iis-8.5

I have a Web API project that makes a remote SOAP call. This works fine in IIS Express (win 7) but it does not work in either IIS 7.5 (win 7) or IIS 8.5 (wind server 2012 R2).

Here's the response in IIS Express

```
{
Content-Length: 429
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 23:00:52 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}
```

And here is the response in IIS 7.5

```
{Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate,NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 22:13:10 GMT
Content-Length: 1293

}
```

I've **disabled** Windows Authentication and **enabled** only Anonymous authentication in IIS 7.5

In fact, I've also done a WinDiff of applicationHost.config and copied over settings that are different (and applicable) from IIS Express to IIS 7.

Web.Config has `<Authentication mode ="None">`

I'm not sure what I have to do to get this working.

**EDIT SOLVED ALREADY**

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517323/exchange-web-service-api-and-401-unauthorized-exception?rq=1) lead me to the answer. And [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5300659/2537701) is how I am passing the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The response from IIS clearly indicates that Windows authentication is enabled. Check the IIS configuration carefully please.

Comment: Well yes that's what it is but I've disabled all Authentcation in IIS except Anonumous Extension not just for the application but at machine level.

Comment: @Chookoos unfortunately you didn't. Either you configured the wrong machine, or you configured it in a wrong way.

Comment: Could it be proxy preventing this? It works just fine in IIS Express. I've gone into IIS management console and disabled all authentications except anonymous.

Comment: Turns out I was not specifying authentication when making a HttpWebRequest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517323/exchange-web-service-api-and-401-unauthorized-exception?rq=1 What threw me off was it was working in IIS Express.